# Node.js: how to debug remotely?

Tags: javascript, node.js, debugging, node-inspector

I have a Linux server (os: Centos, ip: 192.168.1.100) with my node app that I want to debug.
For some reason @office I have to work on a remote client  (ip: 192.168.1.7), since Linux server has no GUI/browser.

I did follow the instruction to use node-inspector, without success...

Here is what I did:

```
$ npm --version
2.14.2

$ node --version
v4.0.0

$ npm install -g node-inspector

$ node-inspector --version
Node Inspector v0.12.3

$ node-debug myApp.js
Node Inspector is now available from http://127.0.0.1:8080/?ws=127.0.0.1:8080&port=5858
Debugging `myApp.js`

Debugger listening on port 5858
```

Then if I open my client browser to `http://127.0.0.1:8080/?ws=127.0.0.1:8080&port=5858`
, I get error `ERR_ADDRESS_UNREACHABLE`.

The same result if I open my client browser  to `http://192.168.1.100:8080/?ws=192.168.1.100:8080&port=5858`.

If (out of curiosity) I open `http://192.168.1.100:5858` I just get:

```
Type: connect
V8-Version: 4.5.103.30
Protocol-Version: 1
Embedding-Host: node v4.0.0
Content-Length: 0
```

I did already open port 8080 and 5858 (to be on the safe side) on my firewall (in `/etc/sysconfig/iptables` I have:

```
...
-A INPUT -m state --state NEW -m tcp -p tcp --dport 8080 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -m state --state NEW -m tcp -p tcp --dport 5858 -j ACCEPT
...
```

).

What do I miss?

---

**UPDATE**:
After @aleung suggestion, I did add `web-host=0.0.0.0` flag to `node-debug` command line, without great success: I always get `ERR_ADDRESS_UNREACHABLE` in browser. Even a `telnet 192.168.1.100 8080` from the `192.168.1.7` client
times-out. Instead, a `telnet 192.168.1.100 5858` answers:

```
Type: connect
V8-Version: 4.5.103.30
Protocol-Version: 1
Embedding-Host: node v4.0.0
Content-Length: 0
```

Which probably means debugger is listening, but it's still unreachable from the client interface :-(

Answer (score 2):

By default node-inspector web server listens on 127.0.0.1, only accept connection from localhost. You have to start node-inspector on your server with option `--web-host=0.0.0.0`：

```
$ node-debug --web-host 0.0.0.0 myApp.js
```

Then open your client browser to `http://server:8080/?ws=server:8080&port=5858`, where *server* is your server IP.

Comment: Thanks! I suppose you mean --web-host, since otherwise I get `Cannot start web-host=0.0.0.0: not found: web-host=0.0.0.0`... However, though your suggestion looks very promising, I keep getting `ERR_ADDRESS_UNREACHABLE` on the browser (after some seconds)... :-(

Comment: Note that --web-host=0.0.0.0 seems doing it's job, since netstat tells me node is now listening on 0.0.0.0:8080, instead of 127.0.0.1:8080 ...

Comment: @MarcoS It's `--web-host`, fixed.

Answer (score 0):

node 7.x

node --inspect :file_name